# DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql object': The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

```
server = "UAT101"
db = "mydb"
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db +';Uid=uat101_read;Pwd=*****')

max_week = pd.read_sql("select max(FWEEK) from mytable", con).astype('int')
max_week = max_week.iloc[0].astype('str')

min_week = pd.read_sql("select min(FWEEK) from SOE_DC_ML_8K.dbo.RAWDATA_DC_CONSOLIDATED where FWEEK in (select distinct top 2 FWEEK from mytable order by FWEEK desc)", con).astype('int')
min_week = min_week.iloc[0].astype('str')

query = "Select [FWEEK],[DPS_NUM] from mytable where (fweek = '"+max_week+"' or (fweek = '"+min_week+"' and NEW_DPS_FLG = '1'))"

df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
```

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '    Select
>   [FWEEK],[DPS_NUM],[COMMODITYDESC],[SYST... Name: 0, dtype: object':
>   The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.

i am getting error while executing `df = pd.read_sql(query, con)` statement

Comment: That code looks very open to injection. with syntax like `'"+max_week+"'`

Comment: Maybe just a typing error: `Select [FWEEK],[DPS_NUM],from mytable where ... ` - remove `,` before `from`.

Comment: @Zhorov while adding question i edited query so missed to remove comma in actual query comma is not there before from

Comment: query = "Select [FWEEK],[DPS_NUM] from mytable where (fweek = '"+max_week+"' or ([fweek] = '{}' or ([fweek] = '{}' and [NEW_DPS_FLG] = '1'))".format(max_week.iloc[0],min_week.iloc[0]) string formatting helped issue resolved